# Interpretation of the parameter estimates from a glm model with proportion data

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, proportion

I have the following model to look at the effect of humidity (AverageHumidity) on the proportion of insects surviving in climate controlled chambers. I have used a glm for proportions.

My response variable is the proportion of males that have survived (Im looking at the sexes separately for now):

```
    ySrubusMale=cbind(Males_survived,Males_died)
```

My model is:

```
    m=glm(ySrubusMale~AverageHumidity, data=chamberData, family=binomial())
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
    Call:
    glm(formula = ySrubusMale ~ AverageHumidity, family = binomial(), 
data = chamberData)

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -1.6619  -0.6637  -0.1952   0.7441   2.0895  

    Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
    (Intercept)      4.90053    1.87168   2.618  0.00884 **
    AverageHumidity -0.06781    0.02597  -2.611  0.00902 **
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

        Null deviance: 35.361  on 26  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 28.198  on 25  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 88.758

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

As the humidity of the environment increases, the proportion of males surviving is reduced. However I want to know how to calculate an effect size. In a simple binary logistic regression, you can use the odds ratio to determine how a unit change in the predictor will change the odds of an outcome occuring. But, when I have used proportions as my response (and not a binary outcome of 0's and 1's) how can I interpret the effect of a unit change in the preidtcor (i.e. humidity) on the proportion of males surviving?

Comment: Is it possible model your problem as a binary classification problem instead? One measurement would be `[died, humidity]` where `died` is a binary variable. Is there a reason to try to model the proportion instead?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Bar. I had different starting numbers of males and females in each chamber (i.e. in each chamber I had 6 males and 11 females) so that is why I used proportions. However, if I am analysing the sexes separately, I suppose that I do not need to account for different initial numbers of insects...In this case, I could treat the response as a binary variable

Comment: In that case you could also add the sex as a independent variable and get back the difference in survival between the sexes. So a data point would be [died, humidity, male], where male=0/1.

Comment: If I added sex as an explanatory variable, can the model account for the fact that there were different numbers of males and females that were added to the chambers (i.e. different initial numbers). If you look at raw counts, it seems that more females survived, but this is because there were more females to begin with. Would a binary logistic regression take into account the different numbers of the sexes?